# How do I get Qt's QProcess working nicely with my signal_handler on embedded LINUX

Tags: qt, thread-safety, signals, embedded-linux

Hello I am having a problem with an embedded Linux device when trying to run a QProcess for candump.

What is happening is that my signal_handler for a comm's port is being triggered multiple times when I have a QProcess running.

Initiating the signal:

```
...
...
/* open the device to be non-blocking (read will return immediatly) */
UString portName = PortName(portNo);
int fd = open(portName, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
if(fd < 0) {
  hCom = 0;
  perror(portName);
  return(false);
}
hCom = fd;

/* install the signal handler before making the device asynchronous */
saio.sa_handler = UCommManager::signal_handler_IO;
UUtility::MemClear(&saio.sa_mask, sizeof(saio.sa_mask));
saio.sa_flags = 0;
saio.sa_restorer = NULL;
sigaction(SIGIO, &saio, &oldSigSettings);
...
...
```

and the QProcess:

```
// Runs system candump to record all CANBUS messages into connected USB
QProcess *CANLogger = new QProcess();
QStringList arg;
arg << "-l" << "can0";
CANLogger->setWorkingDirectory("/disk/usbsda1/");
CANLogger->start("candump", arg);
```

the signal handler:

```
signal_handler_IO(int status)
{
  static bool tempLock = false;
  if(tempLock){
    qDebug() << "1. Blocked";
    return;
  }
  tempLock = true;

  for(ubyte no = 0; no < UComm_Manager.Count(); no++) {
    UComm *dev = UComm_Manager[no].dev;
    if(!dev || !dev->IsOpen()) continue;
    dev->signal_handler_IO(status);
  }
  tempLock = false;
}
```

Without the QProcess running "Blocked" is never printed, but when it is running "Blocked" gets printed multiple times.

If I do not have the tempLock there then my strings that get read in dev->signal_handler_IO(status) gets out of order.

Receiving strings like 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' will give me some lines looking like

bacdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

lmnoabcdefghijkpqrstuvwxyz

etc..

everything is there, but out of order.

What i have tried was to disable and enable signal interrupts with:

```
bool UCommManager::BlockSig(sigset_t *orig_mask)
{
  sigset_t mask;
  sigemptyset (&mask);
  sigaddset (&mask, SIGIO);
  if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, orig_mask) < 0)   // set blocked and saved the old mask to orig_mask
  {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

and

```
bool UCommManager::UnblockSig(sigset_t *orig_mask)
{
  if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, orig_mask, NULL) < 0)
  {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

But they did not fix the problem.

Are there some threading issues that I need to look out for here?

**EDIT:**
Because we are hitting the "blocked" multiple times, this would mean that we are getting interrupted? Should that me possible?  I would have thought the interrupts would be called one after another based on some sort of priority..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use signals at all? Signals are highly problematic due to their asynchronous nature. A signal handler can interrupt your program at the most inconvenient time. Only a certain subset of the POSIX interface can be used safely in a signal handler.

As you are already using Qt, have you looked at the QtSerialPort module?
If this isn't an option you could use the FD you got out of the open() call with a QtSocketNotifier (ignore the name, it's not only about sockets).

Comment: The signals are actually where it ventures into legacy code and shared between multiple software that don't use the Qt library.

Comment: Are there other ways to run system commands besides QProcessor? I worked out that running

    system("candump")

does not cause this issue, but I will will end up having to write up a class to do multiple system calls to handle its status and to kill it.

Comment: in a similar application, I found out that writing to a (mechanical) USB Disk stalls the containing thread for e.g. 100ms regularly. I solved that by logging into a buffer and doing the disk IO in another thread.